# How do I conduct a min unit test in c?

Tags: c, turtle-graphics

I have written code for a parser for the LOGO turtle graphics programming language and need to test it.

I would like to use min unit (http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html#Example) as it seems the most simple way of testing. A small section of my parser code is below. Please could you give me an example using my own code on how to implement the min unit testing?

Thanks in advance:)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int x;
   FILE *input_file;
   Prog input; /* struct to hold file*/

   if (check_inputs(argc) != true) {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   input.current_line = 0;
   for(x=0; x<MAX_LINES; x++) {
     input.words[x][0] = '\0';
   }

   input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (input_file == NULL) {
      fclose(input_file);
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s\n", argv[1]);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   x = 0;
   while(fscanf(input_file, "%s", input.words[x++]) == 1
                                     && x < MAX_LINES) {
      assert(x < MAX_LINES);
   }

   start_parse(&input);
   printf("All instructions parsed okay if no other error messages printed!\n");
   fclose(input_file);
   free(input_file);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*check command line inputs and return file name as a string*/
int check_inputs (int argc)
{
   if (argc != ARG_NUM) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Incorrect number of argumemts.\n");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
 }


/*structs */
struct prog {
   char words[MAX_LINES][MT_SIZE];
   int vars[NUM_VARS];
   int current_line;
   int current_var;
};
typedef struct prog Prog;
```

Comment: Unit tests are usually integrated into build systems, ex. `cmake` has `ctest`. I wouldn't advise it to do manually. How do you build your program? If you have `make all` add a `test` target for build and _running_ also tests. A test is a separate `main()` program that returns `0` if everything is ok.

Comment: Note that `x < MAX_LINES` should be before `fscanf(input_file, "%s", input.words[x++]) == 1` and `assert(x < MAX_LINES);` not needed.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, I will try these out now! It's for an assignment so I need to be able to write my own too

Comment: @chux Thanks, I have amended this now.